# std::make_heap equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, c++, stl

STL has this really useful function. Is there any equivalent to this in Java? I could write my custom implementation but it would be useful not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

`std::make_heap` makes a binary heap, which is used as a priority-queue and is called [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) in Java.

**Correction**: there isn't a standard binary-heap class in Java, but I suggested two in the comment below.

Comment: ...except, of course, when it's used for purposes other than a priority queue (note that the C++ standard library includes both `std::priority_queue` and `std::make_heap`, because the two really aren't synonymous).

Comment: You're quite right I was a bit too quick. But Java doesn't have a standard binary heap class, there is one [here, by Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BinaryHeap.html) and [here one in one file](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse373/11wi/homework/5/BinaryHeap.java)

Answer (score 0):

[PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) has a [special constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Collection-) that can "heapify" an exisisting ArrayList (or any Collection).

Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();

PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(x);  // O(N)
```

This operation copies input whereas `make_heap` just reorders the array in-place.